# Texinfo, how to deal with impossible next / previous?

Tags: emacs, texinfo

I'm trying to write documentation in Texinfo format (must be traditional to Emacs, I guess). And it is a nightmare... Anyway, I could get to the point, where the source gives me less error then when I started, but the errors are impossible to understand and thus fix.

All of the errors boil down to "bad" next / previous / up nodes. And they all happen in places, where there can be no "next", no "previous" and no "up" nodes. I.e. The last node in the list does not have a next node, similarly, the first can't have a previous, and the top-level can't have an "up". Node. These are the exact messages I'm getting:

> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:385: Next field of node
>   `dot-product|join|distinct' not pointed to (perhaps incorrect
>   sectioning?).
>
> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:392: This node (return)
>   has the bad Prev.
>
> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:199: Next field of
>   node `initially' not pointed to (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
>
> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:120: This node (for) has the bad Prev.
>
> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:29: Next field of node `Top' not
>   pointed to (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
>
> ./i-iterate/info/i-iterate.texi:120: This node (for) has the bad Prev.

My texti file structure is as follows:

```
- Top
|- menu-0
|  |- menu-2
|- menu-1
<list of nodes>
```

I.e. nodes mentioned in `menu-2` should have their top node in `menu-0`, and `Top` is the top node for nodes in `menu-0` and `menu-1`.

`for` node is the first node in the `menu-0`, `return` node is the first node in the `menu-1`, `dot-product|join|distinct` is the last node in `menu-2`, `initially` is the last node of the `menu-0`.

Top node can't have previous / next / up nodes... for obvious reasons.

As requested, the offending nodes:

```
@node for, with, , Top
@node return, collect, , Top
@node dot-product|join|distinct, , permutations, for
@node initially, , finally, Top
```

Some more info. I could actually "fix" it by specifying the `return` node as the next node of `initially` and `initially` as a previous node of `return`. But this is not the desired effect, because they two belong in different sets of nodes.

Also, this is how the entire menu looks like:

```
@menu 
* for::       A multi-purpose driver for doing variety of things.
* with::      A driver for variable declaration.
* generate::  A general purpose generator driver.
* repeat::    A simple driver for performing iteration N number of itmes.
* finally::   A driver that runs when the iteration finishes normally.
* initially:: A driver that runs before any code in the iteration.
@end menu

@strong{Keywords}

@menu
* return::   Returns the control flow to the form outside the loop.
* collect::  Generates a list with the cells being the experssion given.
* hash::     Generates a hash-table with the provided keys and values.
* skip::     Skips the execution of the rest of the loop body.
* previous:: Gives the value of the variable from the previous iteration.
* next::     Gives the value of the variable from the next iteration.
* output::   Prints the variable to the dedicated stream.
* insert::   Generates a vector and inserts elements into it.
* minimize:: Finds the minimum value of the variable.
* maximize:: Finds the maximum value of the variable.
* count::    Counts the number ot times this expression was executed.
* sum::      Sums the values of this variable.
* multiply:: Multiplies the values of this variable.
* reduce::   General purpose accumulation handler.
@end menu

@node for, with, , Top
@chapter Multi-purpose driver

... description of what for node is ...

@strong{For continuations}

@menu
* in|on::                     Iterates over lists.
* upfrom|from|downfrom::      Iterates numberically.
* across|reverse|binary::     Iterates over arrays.
* depth-first|breadth-first:: Iterates over trees.
* keys|values|pairs::         Iterates over hash-tables.
* random::                    Produces unique random each iteration.
* chars|words|lines::         Iterates over entities in buffer.
* permutations::              Generates permutation of an array.
* dot-product|join|distinct:: Iterates over sets.
@end menu
```

Comment: Show us the format you use for your `@node`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@node for` and `@node return` without the extra arguments.  Texinfo will then automatically figure out the prev/next/up links based on `@chapter` and other sectioning commands.

Comment: Maybe so, but these are the errors you want to solve rather than the ones you get with the `@node foo, bar, baz`.

Comment: I'd definitely start with a single menu per node.  Also make sure every `@node` is immediately followed by a `@chapter` or `@section` or some such.